# How to implement single sign on in all my sub-domain?

Tags: python, authentication, pyramid

My main domain is `example.com` and I have sub-domain `test.example.com` and `best.example.com`.

I want to share user authentication cookies
in all my sub domain and all user will login from `login.example.com`, any user login will redirect to this login domain.

Answer (score 3):

Using python default AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy and ACLAuthorizationPolicy. In pyramid AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy you have to give a secret key, your sceret key will be same for all sub-domainan and you have give
parent_domain=True in AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy then if you login in login.example.com you automatically login to other sub-domain.

> init.py

```
authn_policy=AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy('seekrit',hashalg='sha512',
             parent_domain=True)
authz_policy = ACLAuthorizationPolicy()
```